# User database storage location (filename / path) in QGIS/Windows

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, file-path

I am using QGIS 3.16 and Windows 10.

I have some custom CRS (cCRS). Now, I'd like to work on my QGIS Projects at another PC and want to move my cCRS there.

According to the QGIS manual the cCRS are stored in the "user database". But I cannot find any further information about filename or path of the "user database" in the manual.
I also tried to search for my cCRS-names in the Explorer (search for files including content). I searched in the (typical) user and programm directories, but haven't succeeded yet.

Does anybody have an idea for me?

In response to [@JGH's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/409372/115) I am including a picture of my folder contents:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the menu `settings / user profiles / open active profile folder`, which by default, on Windows, should lead to something like `C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\`

Then have a look at `qgis.db` and its table `tbl_srs`

Comment: _ @JGH Thanks for your quick answer. And sorry for my late response. I ran a little bite out of the the last days. I found the the `qgis.db`, **but not** the `tbl_srs`. 
I edited my question by adding my default directory content, if you may have a look?
What is the sense of the `tbl_srs`?

Comment: @jaysigg the table `tbl_srs` is inside the SQLlite DB `qgis.db`. Go the menu `layer / data source manager` and select `Browser` then go to `qgis.db` and add the said table. Alternatively you can use a tool such as [sqlitebrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: Ok, found it, thanks. But what you mean with "**add** the [tbl_srs] table"? Add to what?